# Check if a cell contains valid data

Tags: google-sheets

I have applied the data validation in Google Sheets, now the user gets a warning and a red corner in a cell if the value in a cell is not from a selected range. However, I would like to check with my script if the value in a cell C1 is valid or not.

Is there something similar to 'ISERR(C1)' but for validation?

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on your use case? As in, is this check going to be run frequently (eg onEdit or something), or occasionally? If the latter, the only think I can think of (untested) is to get the value, get the validation rule, in a spare cell set the validation rule with strict enforcement, and then try setting the value and see if it throws an error. But as I say, impractical to do frequently.

Comment: But re-reading, you could of course write a script that performs the validation itself (gets the value, gets the range from validation rule, and test with iteration etc).

Comment: Yes, the validation needs to run often. I will need to write a script myself if there is no other solution, but that is why I asked the question.